# Error insercion SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy realizando una insercion a mi BD en sql server y me genera el siguiente mensaje de error:

```
Failed to insert into 'GroupMember' table, responseCode: 19 Error Message: PRIMARY KEY must be unique
```

Soy nuevo en esto de SQL por lo cual recurro a su ayuda

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro. Estás duplicando la llave primaria de la tabla. Es decir, el registro nuevo tiene la misma llave primaria que un registro que ya existe y eso no es posible, pues la llave primaria debe ser única para cada registro.

Comment: Si puedes indicar que datos estas tratando de insertar así como la estructura de la tabla nos ayudará a formular la solución que necesitas. Como muestra el mensaje estas insertando en la columna que tienes como (PK) un valor que ya existe, si tu tabla tiene esa columna como por ejemplo (Id INT identity(1,1)) no hace falta que en el insert incluyas ese campo ya que se completará solo, por ejemplo "INSERT INTO GroupMember (Nombre, Grupo)  VALUES('Juan','Grupo1')" en este caso ese es un insert valido si tu tabla tiene las columnas (Id, Nombre, Grupo). Espero te ayude